# Mathematica FullSimplify becomes less simplified with more specific assumptions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

As far as I always understood, *Mathematica* always assumes an expression to represent the most general state. For example, a variable is usually assumed to be `Complex`.

Given the following expression:

```
expr = (g^2 q^3 (2 mN Sqrt[mR^5 (mN^2 + q^2)] + 2 mN Sqrt[mR^5 (m\[Pi]^2 + q^2)] + 2 Sqrt[mR^5 (mN^2 + q^2) (m\[Pi]^2 + q^2)] + mR^(5/2) (2 mN^2 + 3 m\[Pi]^2 + 4 q^2)))/(12 mR^( 3/2) m\[Pi]^4 \[Pi] (mN + Sqrt[mN^2 + q^2]))
```

where all variables are positive I make the following observation my system with

```
$Version
13.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)
```

```
FullSimplify[expr,mR>0&&mN>0]
```

manages to extract `mR` out of all square roots in the numerator and cancels it with the factor of `mR^(3/2)` in the denominator, giving an overall factor of `mR`. To reiterate, at this point my understanding is that *Mathematica* still believes all other unspecified variables to be Complex and thus simplifications should be more restrictive.

```
(g^2 mR q^3 (3 m\[Pi]^2 + 4 q^2 + 2 Sqrt[(mN^2 + q^2) (m\[Pi]^2 + q^2)] + 2 mN (mN + Sqrt[mN^2 + q^2] + Sqrt[m\[Pi]^2 + q^2])))/(12 m\[Pi]^4 \[Pi] (mN + Sqrt[mN^2 + q^2]))
```

**However**, if I add in one more assumption, thus making it more specific, *Mathematica* backtracks and is no longer able to cancel the factor of `mR`, giving me a result that I, as a human, would deem less simplified.

```
FullSimplify[expr, mR > 0 && mN > 0 && q > 0]

(g^2 q^3 (2 mN Sqrt[mR^5 (mN^2 + q^2)] + 2 mN Sqrt[mR^5 (m\[Pi]^2 + q^2)] + 2 Sqrt[mR^5 (mN^2 + q^2) (m\[Pi]^2 + q^2)] + mR^(5/2) (2 mN^2 + 3 m\[Pi]^2 + 4 q^2)))/(12 mR^(
 3/2) m\[Pi]^4 \[Pi] (mN + Sqrt[mN^2 + q^2]))
```

What is happening here, and how can I prevent this from happening, other than calling `FullSimplify` multiple times?

Comment: Did you try `Simplify[PowerExpand[expr]]`?

Comment: @user64494 No I did not, but that seems to work.